# Win 2003 Server: corrupted folder / free disk space

Tags: windows-server-2003, disk-space-utilization, corruption

I have a corrupted folder on my win 2003 server which is occupying a lot of hd space,
unfortunately there's no way deleting it - when showing its properties it shows several GB of occupied space but when viewing the content itself it doesn't show anything ..
any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: What is the folder called? It might be a system folder you shouldn't be messing with. For example, if it's `System Volume Information` or `WinSxS`... **leave well alone**!

Comment: How do you know it's corrupted?

Comment: Make a backup before you start playing around w/ it.

Answer (score 3):

Without some more information, it could be a couple things.  It could be that what's in the folder are protected OS files that you wouldn't be able to view by default.  You need to go into folder options and check the "view protected operating system files" to see those.  I wouldn't necessarily recommend deleting those right off the bat, however, as usually that causes Bad Things to happen.

Alternatively, if it is folder corruption, you should run `chkdsk` to verify this.  You can run it with `/p` first to verify, then run it with `/f` to try and fix the errors if any are found.

Answer (score 0):

If the points identified by Holocryptic has been satisfied and the problem/situation persists, then you might also consider mounting that file volume under a 'nix distro which has NTFS support to see if it offers more control towards resolving it.

Comment: Just in case, mounting a corrupted NTFS volume under many of the unix distros often makes the volume unrecoverable by any tool.  I would only try that as a last resort.

Comment: To be fair and accurate, your mileage may vary - use at your own risk, but it is a viable option in same cases and more so with the recent 'nix implementations.